# Generate keyword automaticly from post titles

Tags: php, wordpress, split, title

For example I have title "The Battleship Trailer"
so it will generate keyword like this
"best , player, of, the, world"
how can i do it ?

I want to apear in html like this...

```
First:The
Second:Battleship
Third:Trailer

<meta name="keywords" content="<FirstWord>,<second>,<third>"/>
```

More exactly i want to split the title in words.

I use Wordpress

Comment: Not sure why you are using `"best , player, of, the, world"` as your example... you obviously mean `"the, battleship, trailer"` for arguments sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be better to get the post's slug. That will **sanitize and strip out any shorter  words** that won't be of any value to search engines. Then explode and implode with PHP...

**Here how:**

```
 // Get the global post variable (inside or outside the loop)
 global $post;

 // Seperate title slug by dashes into array
 $the_slug_into_array = explode('-', $post->post_name);

 // Convert array back into a string with comma separation
 $the_keywords = implode(',', $the_slug_into_array );

 // Echo out the string of terms from the title
 echo $the_keywords;
```

*Let me know if this worked for you...*

Answer (score 6):

```
echo '<meta name="keywords" content="'.implode(',', explode(' ', $string)).'"/>';
```

This would join the words separated by a space in `$string` with a comma. Obviously replace `$string` the proper variable.

Comment: What explode does is it separates the string into chunks, an array you can play with if you must. Using implode joins an array into one piece with a "glue," in your case a comma.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = get_the_title(); // Inside your header.php 
echo '<meta name="keywords" content="'.implode(',', explode(' ', $string)).'"/>';
```

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_the_title

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php